# SignalR: Proxy hub not generating correctly

Tags: c#, signalr

I've made updates to my 'hub'. Specifically, I've added a few new methods. It works fine when I debug within VS 2012. However, when I publish it to my local IIS the signalr/hubs is still generating the old proxy hub. The new methods aren't listed.

To ensure it wasn't an older version of the assembly, I ran it through ILSpy and I can see the new methods.

I've tried something minor, modifying the HubName attribute to see if even that change would be reflected in the new proxy hub. It isn't.

Any thoughts on how to force the signalr/hubs url to generate the proper proxy? I've tried adding ?120 etc onto the end to see if it's cached, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and no amount of App Pool recycling, IIS restarting or any other similar thing helps. It's an MVC application, and accessing the "signalr/hubs" javascript shows me the default proxy, without any of the methods I defined. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the site was being deployed as a sub-application. It has another application sitting above it so the url for the signalr/hubs that we copied from the samples was wrong for our build. We needed it to be relative, so adding the ~ onto the front fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

İf you recycled application pool and still not working,

Instead of changing the AssemblyVersion attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs change AssemblyFileVersion, this will leave all the loading of your Assembly untouched but give you the option to look at the deployed version in the GAC.

The normal location for shared assemblies are stored in the  Global Assembley Cache aka. GAC.
To add or remove assembles use the Visual Studio or Microsoft Net Gac utility. Other alternative for GAC operations [GACView v1.11 - Global Assembly Cache (GAC) Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/dot_net_tools/gac_viewer.html)

Comment: This isn't a shared assembly. It's an web application. The assembly is deployed to the bin.